# Copying and renaming a template worksheet depending on a range of cell values on a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template sheet that I have set up named "Template".

I have a range of cells on another worksheet called "Formulation" that I would like it to look through the range "G7:W7" and create a copy of the "Template" and rename it accordingly.

I have adapted a piece of code I have found but I keep encountering a run time error 13 - type mismatch.

Here is the code:

```
`Sub CopyInfoSheetandInsert()
'
' CopyInfoSheetandInsert Macro
'
Dim rcell As Range
Dim Background As Worksheet
Set Background = Sheets("Formulation")

For Each rcell In Range("D7:W7")

    If rcell.Value <> "" Then

          Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets("COSHH")
          Sheets("Template (2)").Name = rcell.Value

    End If

Next rcell



End Sub
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

By moving the macro button to the formulation page the copy function now works however, on the following line of code I now get a subscript out of range error?

```
Sheets("Template(2)").Name = rcell.Value
```

Kind Regards,

Aidan

Comment: On which line ? What's the value in rcell.value ?

Comment: so in the range there are several merged cells that generally contain incremental text i.e. "A","B","C", but it could also contain text saying "A1", "A2", "A3".

Comment: It might not solve your issue but rather than assuming the new sheet will be called "Template(2)" why not use `Sheets(Sheets("COSHH").Index - 1).Name = rcell.Value`

Comment: Ok that works beautifully, except it now isn't looping!! is it due to the location of my end if? should that be later in the code?

Comment: So if you put `debug.print rcell.address` before `Next rcell` does it keep bringing back the same address in the immediate window?

Comment: Sorry my friend, that previous answer had worked! I had removed the range so it was unique to one cell, ID10T error. 

I have one final question if you have the time/patience to help a newbie..

How can I adjust the code to skip over duplicates? for example.. if I needed to run the code again because for example.. "C" has been added to "A" and "B"..

It tries to readd "A" and I get a run time error 1004 - name is already taken!

Comment: I've solved that for you in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like:

```
Sub CopyInfoSheetandInsert()

Dim rcell As Range
Dim Background As Worksheet
Set Background = Sheets("Formulation")

For Each rcell In Range("D7:W7")

    If rcell.Value <> "" And SheetExists(rcell.Value) = False Then

          Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=Sheets("COSHH")
          Sheets(Sheets("COSHH").Index - 1).Name = rcell.Value

    End If

Next rcell
End Sub

Function SheetExists(SheetName) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

'Assume Failure
SheetExists = False

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name = SheetName Then
        'Success
        SheetExists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next sht

End Function
```

Comment: Still not quite there.. for example

It has generated sheets.. "A", "B"..

if I now add "C" onto the "Formulation" page.. It copies the sheet as "Template (2)" and I think it still is trying to name it page "A" as I am getting a "Name is already taken" error.

Again, thank you for your patience and your help!

Comment: Hi Tim!

Your code has worked absolutely perfectly but I seem to have broken it without actually changing the code!

I have combined it in a module which calls on 2 previously written subs, but now I get a type mismatch (error 13) on the following line:

    If rcell.Value <> "" And SheetExists(rcell.Value) = False Then

Any Ideas? Sorry to pester you again but I am sure it is something simple. 

Kind Regards

(I am running it from a different page, but even when assigning just your code and running it I get the same error)

Comment: Is the function in a module or is it on a sheet? Also what is rcell.Value populated with? If it's empty or null then you could run into issues. Technically you should also qualify `Range("D7:W7")` so specify what Sheet you're referring to also. This could be part of your issue as it will default to `ActiveSheet`.